# Match single row from second table with multiple matches with many columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the two joined tables below.  I'd like to get only the one line from the REQUIREMENTS table with the most recent date (3/8/2019).

```
**PART**                **REQUIREMENTS**            
ID      OH  TIME        PART    ORDER   QTY DATE
5512    5   21          5512    74619   102 3/8/2019
                        5512    74907   25  3/10/2019
                        5512    74908   41  3/19/2019
                        5512    74243   59  3/21/2019
```

When I use Min(REQUIREMENTS.DATE), I still get all four rows because of the unique data in both the ORDER and QTY tables.  I'm pretty sure I need to use `Select Top 1 [...]` but I'm having trouble figuring out where to use it.  Ultimately I'm looking to return:

```
PART    DATE        OH  TIME    ORDER   QTY
5512    3/8/2019    5   21      74619   102
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction (SQL Server 2012)?  Thanks in advance!

Dan

Comment: please insert some tables and data reproducing code so we can create situation in our env.

Comment: The data is similar to what I have shown.  The PART table has over 12k parts.  The REQUIREMENTS table has at least 10 lines per part.  Each line has different ORDER, QTY and DATE parameters.  I'm trying to get each part from the PART table to match only one line from the REQUIREMENTS table.  My query with Min(DATE) matches one line per part.  But once I add the other columns, it get multiple lines because of the unique data.  I hope this makes sense.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `APPLY`, your choice if you want `OUTER` or `CROSS`.

```
SELECT p.ID, p.state, p.time
    , r.qty, r.date1
FROM dbo.Part p
OUTER APPLY (
    select top 1 qty, date
    from dbo.Requirements
    where part = p.ID
    order by date1
) as r
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  This works great in SSMS but for some reason the report writing application I'm using doesn't accept OUTER or CROSS APPLY.  I get "unexpected token OUTER".  I also tried LEFT OUTER JOIN but get an EOF error.  I'm still stuck so any other suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: What report writer app are you using?  does it support stored procedures?

Comment: SmartViews.  It's from our ERP reseller (home grown).  I think it's built on the DevExpress platform.  It doesn't support stored procedures but I got it to work by creating a SQL View with your solution.  I appreciate your guidance.  Thanks!

Comment: Try a stored procedure then?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a correlated subquery to do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM PART P
    INNER JOIN REQUIREMENTS R ON
        P.ID = R.PART
WHERE REQUIREMENTS.[DATE] = (SELECT MAX([DATE] FROM REQUIREMENTS WHERE R.PART = PART)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately this only returns the parts that match the oldest dates (in my case, I'm using Min).  For example, when I sort the REQUIREMENTS table by date asc, the oldest date is 2003-11-4.  There are three parts with that date and therefore your query only returns the three parts that match that oldest date.  Any other suggestions?